# Updating an array nested in an array of object in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to update the state using React Hooks. I have an array of objects, within an object is another array I am trying to update. All these are generated dynamically.

```js
[
    {
      "question": 2,
      "choices": ["Heart Disease", "GERD", "ASTMA"]
    },
    {
      "question": 4,
      "choices": ["Heart Disease", "GERD", "ASTMA"]
    },
    {
      "question": 9,
      "choices": ["Heart Disease", "GERD", "ASTMA"]
    }
  ]
```

My state looks like this. I am creating a form that contains multiple choices for different questions on the same page. So if I am on question 2, I want to be able to add (or remove) to the choices on that question.

How can I do this using `useState`?

Comment: If above is saved in state? What is the other object you want to save in state? What exactly you mean by `I want to be able to add (or remove) to the choices on that question.`?

Comment: Add some of your current code would help

Answer (score 1):

In order to update the nested state, you need to map over the state and update the specific question id.

**Here is the code for adding and removing choices.**

```js
let initialState = [
    {
        "question": 2,
        "choices": ["Heart Disease", "GERD", "ASTMA"]
    },
    {
        "question": 4,
        "choices": ["Heart Disease", "GERD", "ASTMA"]
    },
    {
        "question": 9,
        "choices": ["Heart Disease", "GERD", "ASTMA"]
    }
];

const [questions, setQuestions] = React.useState(initialState);

const addChoice = (questionId, choice) => {
    setQuestions(question.map(q => {
        if(q.question === questionId){
            return {...q, choices: [...q.choices, choice]}
        }
        return q;
    }))
};

const removeChoice = (questionId, choice) => {
    setQuestions(question.map(q => {
        if(q.question === questionId){
            return {...q, choices: q.choices.filter(c => c !== choice)}
        }
        return q;
    }))
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you meant that you need to change the choices based on the question number dynamically. Then maybe below should do the job. It is written on the fly and not tested.

```
const [questions, setQuestions] = React.useState(defaultObject);

function questionSelected(questionNumber) {
    const temp = questions;
    const question = temp.find(n => n.question == questionNumber);
    question.choices = ['New', 'Choices'];
    setQuestions([...temp]);
}
```

Hope it helps.